# Unsure if I correctly added my SHA256 code to GitHub correctly; Terminal gave strange readout

Tags: git, macos, terminal, sha256

Today I was working on setting up my SHA256 code to GitHub, following the tutorial that I found on the Odin Project's [Website](https://www.theodinproject.com/paths/foundations/courses/foundations/lessons/setting-up-git) and came across some strange readouts from terminal when I was trying to test the connection with the tutorial that the lesson linked to on [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection). When I was testing, my terminal gave me this reading:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.255.113' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/(my_username)/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Received disconnect from 192.30.255.113 port 22:11: Bye Bye
Disconnected from 192.30.255.113 port 22
```

What does this mean? I am pretty new at terminal and git in general, so I want to make sure I didn't mess anything up or leave myself vulnerable in any way. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Best,
O

Comment: "When I was testing" Testing how? Tell us what you said in the Terminal.

Comment: Show the rest of the evidence you're looking at: what exactly were you trying to do, not some link that led you to try something, what did you try? What else did it say? This isn't a guessing game were you conceal as much as possible and everyone eagerly tries to fill in the blanks.

Comment: I'm confused by your mention of SHA256, as Git SHA256 is not generally live yet, and ssh does not use SHA256. Your entire question seems to be centered on RSA-ssh access to GitHub, which should work given a large enough RSA key. Use `ssh -Tvvv git@github.com` to observe ssh going through its security checking to see if GitHub accept your public key and convert that to "allow access to you". If they don't, some of the verbose output will pinpoint where things have gone wrong.

Comment: My apologies! The command I entered before that was `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. After I got the ssh-rsa code readout, I ran the command `ssh -T git@github.com` then when prompted to confirm the RSA SHA256 key, I entered `yes` to continue where I got that message. This was the command that I read was used to check the connection and verify that I completed the process correctly. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not what github gives me for my key, so there might be something wrong, but the easy way to tell is to try using your key to clone something.  Try`git clone git@github.com:githubtraining/hellogitworld`.

Comment: The disconnect makes me suspect you're trying to ssh out through a corporate firewall that doesn't like traffic it can't inspect, but I that's not much more than a guess.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.